# How to show this set has countably many elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $E$ be the set of rational-valued sequences with only finitely many nonzero entries. Does $E$ have only countably many elements?

How would I go about approaching this problem? I have tried applying the usual techniques and theorems but am stuck.

Comment: Do you know the cardinality of "integer sequences with finitely many nonzero entries"? Can you prove that it's countable / uncountable?

Comment: Can this comment be helpful?

Answer (score 6):

Hint: This  set is  the union over  $n$ of the sets $A_n=\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_N,0,0,.....): x_i \in \mathbb Q  \, \forall i\}$.

Can you show that each $A_n$ is countable?